# About a $\sigma$-finite measure

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal H,P)$ and a real random variable $X$ such that $E(X)$ is well defined (also infinite values are allowed). Is it true that the measure
$$\mu(A):=E(X\chi_A)=\int_A X\,dP$$
is a $\sigma$-finite measure? Clearly if $X\in L^1$ we obtain a finite measure, but I'm interested at the general case when $E(X)$ can be also $\infty$.

Thans in advance.

Comment: If $X\in L^1_{loc}$ you are in the clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "real random variable" you mean the values are real?  That is, we have $P(X=\infty)=0$ ?  Then sets
$$
A_n = \{ X < n \}
$$
have finite measure, and
$$
\Omega = \bigcup_{n} A_n .
$$

Comment: Yes I mean that the values are real.